# Does wifi scanning comply with Apple's guidelines to scan wifi hotspot on ios4

Tags: iphone

Does wifi scanning comply with Apple's guidelines to scan wifi hotspot on ios4

Comment: @Close-voters: Why is this off-topic...?

Comment: By legal, do you mean "allowed by the SDK rules"? It's definitely legal, and it's almost certainly allowed by the SDK.

Comment: Impossible to answer in general terms. Will depend from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. Although just scanning for available signals can hardly be illegal anywhere

Comment: Legal questions don't belong here. We're programmers, not lawyers.

Comment: reopen, because it is not a "legal" question (just poorly worded). It is about Apple's guidelines for app development.  @prajakta: please fix the question unless this is really about laws.

Comment: Concur, @Thilo, with the question update. This one's probably okay.

Comment: I was right on this not actually referring to "legal" as in laws related to wi-fi scanning. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

"Is it legal?" is a very unwise question here for the following reasons:

- legality depends on (at a minimum) your jurisdiction, which you haven't supplied.
- despite the armchair lawyers here, the vast majority of us are *not* lawyers, not *your* lawyers, and probably not allowed to give legal advice at all.
- advice off the net is worth every cent you paid for it.

---

Now that the question has changed to "Does it comply with Apple's guidelines?", that's another matter.

The AppStore guidelines are [made available](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) by Apple but you have to be already registered as a developer to get them. Despite the sometimes seemingly arbitrary nature of rejections complained about on the web (and I have no idea whether those complaints are justified), these guidelines should be a good starting point.

That same page also shows an appeals process if you think your application was rejected wrongly so it looks like Apple is at least making the process a little more transparent.

While I disapprove of the iDevices being so locked down (Apple returning to the halcyon days of IBM mainframes where the operators in their ivory towers had full control over what you were allowed to do - what was the personal computer revolution for if not to free us up from that?), this is at least a little encouraging, although I have to wonder how much of that is fear of Android :-)

Answer (score 3):

Considering that's how the iPhone - any any other WiFi device - finds and connects to a hotspot, yes.

Comment: so you mean i can use my scanning algo in my app and play with wifi scanning??

Comment: so you meant legal as in "in line with Apple's guidelines for iOS apps"? That's a different question...

Comment: @Thilo If scanning wireless hotspots and displaying their signal strength was illegal, wireless devices would be illegal. They all do that.

Comment: i just want my app not to be rejected just cause i am using wifi scanning ...?? so can  i use or not??

Comment: of course it is not illegal. But the question seems to be about what Apple allows you to do in an app, which is a very limited subset of your legal options.

Comment: so whats the ans ...will they approve my app  if i use wifiscanning??

Comment: @prajakta: I'm sure they will.

Answer (score 0):

Does it comply with Apple? You're really asking if Apple will reject it? You can just send it and find out. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: It's often not worth all those days/weeks of waiting.

Comment: It looks like this is integral to app. If it is it doesn't really cost much.